# Visual Studio Code isn't working most of the modules ex. (PIL,pygame etc)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

when I try to import PIL it's says "no module named PIL" error coming up. I did install PIL and try several things same thing happen with pygame earlier. please help me out.

## I'm using MacOs Catalina 10.15.3

VS Code
  Python 3.7.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to select the right python environment, check [Using Python environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#:~:text=To%20select%20a%20specific%20environment,or%20library%20versions%20as%20needed.)